# Python3 install with nix mess PATH

Tags: python, nix

I installed Python 3.6 on Debian 9 with

```
nix-env -i python3-3.6.2
```

but now my python interpreter has changed from the default Python 2.7 to this Python 3.6.2:

```
which python
/home/user/.nix-profile/bin/python
```

and this breaks a lot of stuff. How can I install Python 3.6 without replacing the standard Python interpreter?

Comment: Change your path. Or rename that python script to python3

Comment: @pvg it isn't that simple, because packages are (tend to be) immutable  for Nix.

Comment: @danbst i assume using nix doesn't make it impossible to change your path env var.

Comment: @pvg, sure, one can workaround with `rm /home/user/.nix-profile/bin/python`. On second thought, it even doesn't look like workaround, but a proper solution.

Answer (score 3):

That's right, `python3` on Nixpkgs provides `python` executable. The root cause of this is that user installed programs hide system-wide programs (see your `PATH` envvar).

You should install `python2` too, and solve the priority override for `python` executable.

But you may be interested in `nix-shell -p python3` instead, which creates temporal environment with python3 and leaves python 2 elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks. I want to keep the system python2 being python, not install another python. And how can I create a virtualenv with nix-shell?

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46166345/python3-install-with-nix-mess-path/46173165?noredirect=1#comment79308708_46166345 . For environment just type `nix-shell -p python3` in terminal and you'll be dropped to python3. Nix doesn't replace virtualenv in CLI, but you can do `nix-shell -p python3 python3Packages.virtualenv`